# What is the difference between using 0 and 0x0 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Hi i am using SQL Server 2012.Recently i was working on getting count of rows from each table for a Database.I found there were 4 different ways to get that but the 1 which is fast i found is using Partition stats i.e. "**dm_db_partition_stats**" and "**sys.objects**". However while making join i see in where condition it used like "**is_ms_shipped=0x0**". My question is there any difference between using "**is_ms_shipped=0**" and "**is_ms_shipped=0x0**" ? can somebody please help me to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x0` is a literal of datatype `varbinary(1)` and value `0x00`. (A single byte with all bits set to 0).

The binary datatypes have the [lowest data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) so if compared against [a `bit` column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190324.aspx) it will get implicitly cast to that datatype. Resulting in `0`.

You should just use 0 as it avoids the implicit cast and unnecessary obfuscation of using `0x0`.

Comment: ohh wow that something new about 0 and 0x0.i have checked for execution plan but didnt see warning generated by Query optimizer about IMPLICIT_CONVERSION.

Comment: It happens at compile time not run time. The plan has `=(0)` whether or not you use `=0` or `=0x0`